# SQL Server stored prcedure definition is different with sys_modules.definition

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, module, sys, sysobjects

I have 10 stored procedures they are different with their definition in sys_modules. I find them with this query:

```
select 
    b.definition, a.name 
from 
    sysObjects a 
left outer join 
    sys.sys_modules b on b.id = a.object_id 
where 
    b.definition not like '%' + b.name + '%'
```

Could someone tell me why this happens?

It's the second time I faced this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if you use `sp_rename` and is explicitly called out [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql)

> Renaming a stored procedure, function, view, or trigger **will not
>   change the name of the corresponding object name in the definition
>   column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view**. Therefore, we recommend
>   that sp_rename not be used to rename these object types. Instead, drop
>   and re-create the object with its new name.

Note that the rename functionality in SSMS object explorer does in fact call this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES and get the ROUTINE_DEFINITION column for stored procedures